# In Angular template syntax, when using nested *ngFor (or ngForOf) is it possible to keep track of the absolute count of lower level items?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Sorry if I explained the situation poorly in the title. What I have is a situation where there's a component displaying the contents an array within an array, e.g.

```
Input() categories: {
  id: number;
  type: number;
  items: {
    id: number;
    type: number;
    display: string;
  }[];
}[];
```

The length of the items array is not constant.

The items are to be displayed in an apparently flat list (independent of "category" which is essentially hidden to the user), and the categories and items both need to be sorted, i.e.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories | categorySort">
  <li *ngFor="let item of category.items | itemSort : category.type">
    <button (click)="doSomething(category.id, item.id)">
      {{ item.display }}
    </button>
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

But here's the hard part: I need to keep track of how many items are being displayed, so that I can mark some of them (say all the items after the 10th item) as hideable, e.g.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of category.items | itemSort : category.type"
    [class.hideable]="itemNo >= 10">
```

I know that ngFor gives access to the index, but I'm not sure how useful that would be in this situation, as the inner index is not privy to how many items existed in the prior categories.

I know this would be easy if it were being done purely in JS/TS (either by defining some variable external to the for loops to count the items, or by using something like Array.prototype.reduce), but I'm trying to figure out if this can be done purely in the template.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to do something like this

First get the transformed array

```
(categories | categorySort) as pipedArray
```

then, use a reducer to accumulate the total count until the current index

```
(pipedArray.slice(0, i).reduce(reducer, 0)+j) < 15
```

Where `j` is the inner loop's index.

Looks something like this,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(categories | categorySort) as pipedArray">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let category of pipedArray index as i">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of category.items | itemSort : category.type index as j">
            <li *ngIf="(pipedArray.slice(0, i).reduce(reducer, 0) + j) < 15">
                <button>
                    {{ item.display }}
                </button>
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

You still have to declare your reducer function in your component class though

```
public reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator += currentValue.items.length;
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reducer-template-updated?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)